# Database design, many rows or many columns?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am aware that this has been discussed before, but I've read conflicting information about this particular topic, so I'm hoping for a bit more decisive opinions from you.

I have multiple tables, which stand in a 1:1 relationship to a main table linked by a foreign key.

The largest of these tables, the parameter table, has about 1000 columns by now, each of the columns holding a single numerical parameter.

The table in question has a size of about 16 MB with 7000 rows right now.

After creating a normalized structure (ID, Key, Value) and inserting all the data into this new table, it turned into 3 million rows (after filtering out the columns that hadn't been used in the table with the many columns) and a size of 107 MB.

Now I'm wondering, if the effort is really worth the gain. Sure, it's a lot more scalable (I've had to add columns manually way too often lately to make sure it continued to work), but like this I have up to 1000 rows to sort through and I'm just not sure any more.

Some input would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Edit: The majority of the operations will be 'SELECT', followed by UPDATE/INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE respectively (the later is for the relational approach)

Comment: In general many rows are faster to deal(insert,update,delete) with in a db than many columns even if the size is much bigger.

Comment: @Mihai The majority of the operations will be SELECT, does it apply to SELECT too?

Comment: @Mihai Which is exactly why I'm attempting to redesign the database now, before we actually get a problem. A lot of work to be sure, but if I do it right, I'll never have to touch it ever again. Here's hoping. :)

Comment: The question is really about table composition, or rather, table decomposition.  The subject of table decomposition usually comes up in discussions about normalization.  Is your question really about whether normalizing speeds up or slows down database operations?

Comment: @WalterMitty My question is, essentially, if it's really worth all the trouble or if I'm shooting myself in the foot with my endeavor. The 'Many-Columns' approached has worked for years now and I'll need to invest a lot of time and effort into revamping it into something that'll keep working even to the future. And I am to do this, I want to do it:
a) Right
b) With a payoff in terms of performance. (The queries most certainly aren't getting simpler with this model)

Comment: EAV <> normalized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has [limits](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits), such as 1017 columns in an InnoDB table (as of 5.6.9).

If you are not filtering or sorting on most of the columns, put them in a `JSON` string and put that string in a `TEXT` (or maybe `MEDIUMTEXT`) column.

A key-value store can lead to lots of `JOINs`.  The [limit](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#selects) is 61.

I'm confused -- Do you have 1000 sets of 7000 parameters?  Or what?  If it is a *single* set of parameters, then a single key-value table makes some sense.

Comment: I beg your pardon for not responding for so long. To answer your question, a single parameter set has 1000 columns and I have 7000 of those as of right now (number growing). And each time a new parameter needs to be added, it needs to be added as a column, meaning that all the datasets get that parameter added, regardless of whether they need it or not.

Putting it into a text-column instead of 1000 columns is an interesting idea though.